# Obtener los datos sin duplicar de ciertas columnas de una fila concreta con SQL y Python

Tags: python, sql, python-3.x, postgresql

Estoy haciendo una serie de consultas desde python y quiero obtener los datos de dos columnas concretas a partir de la fila donde tengo un valor máximo. Esto lo conseguido,

```
query = "SELECT data_id, data_timestamp FROM dev_data WHERE data_id = (SELECT MAX(data_id) FROM dev_data);"
cur.execute(query)
valor = cur.fetchall()
print(valor)
```

El problema está que al imprimir me sale una lista con el valor deseado pero duplicada.

```
[(2462599, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 9, 10, 52, 199000)), (2462599, datetime.datetime(2020, 3, 3, 9, 10, 52, 199000))]
```

¿Cómo hago para solo tenerla **una sola vez**?
Imagino que es `.fetchall()` y que debe ser algo facilísimo pero no veo que otra opción es la correcta.

Gracias!!

Comment: Un pregunta tonta, pero hay que hacerla: ¿has verificado que no tengas dos filas con el mismo data_id en la tabla?

Comment: Con Select Distinct

Answer (score 0):

Existen 2 soluciones.
En el query le puedes agregar al final 'LIMIT 1'

```
query = "SELECT data_id, data_timestamp FROM dev_data WHERE data_id = (SELECT MAX(data_id) FROM dev_data) LIMIT 1;"
```

O solo tomas el primer valor de la lista.
valor[0]